# CSS opacity change on div with time delay not user interaction

Tags: css, opacity

I'm trying to set up an image within a div that will slowly appear (opacity from 0 to 1) over 5 seconds. I have this code:

```
.fadeDivIn {
opacity: 1;
transition: opacity 5s ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 5s ease-in;
-webkit-transition: opacity 5s ease-in;
-o-transition: opacity 5s ease-in;
}
```

but I can't figure out how to trigger it automatically.

I've been doing transitions to other elements with CSS3 keyframes and would ideally like to apply something similar to opacity but have hit a brick wall. Can anyone help please?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the following example , you need to use keyframes

```
div {
    background: #333;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-animation: smooth 5s ease-in;
    -moz-animation: smooth 5s ease-in;
    -o-animation: smooth 5s ease-in;
    -ms-animation: smooth 5s ease-in;
    animation: smooth 5s ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes smooth {
    0% { opacity: 0;}
    100% { opacity: 1;}
}
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/zxx8u/1/

Comment: Thanks srekoble - this is ideal! I have added 10 seconds to the animation so that I can delay the launch: 
        -moz-animation: smooth 5s ease-in 10s;
       -o-animation: smooth 5s ease-in 10s;
       -ms-animation: smooth 5s ease-in 10s;
       animation: smooth 5s ease-in 10s;

Answer (score 7):

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/9PfMF/

```
div{
    -webkit-animation: fadein 5s linear 1 normal forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein{
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery animate instead, very clean and easy to manipulate.

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/j7yb213r/5/)

```
<div style="opacity:0;">some text</div>
$("div").animate({opacity: '1'}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that works for me:

```css
.chat-messages li{
  -webkit-animation: fadein 5s linear 1 normal forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein{
  0% { opacity: 1;}
  90% { opacity: 1;}
  100% { opacity: 0;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with simple css3 keyframe animation

[demo](http://cdpn.io/FJziy)

```
<div class="timedelay"></div>

.timedelay {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-animation: myanim 5s ease 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myanim {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not from me - but prob because the question was about changing opacity not margin-left.