# JavaScript + CSS3 animations not working properly?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am currently programming a library called `quickly.js`. There are `conceal(milliseconds)` and `display()` functions, which have animations that are programmed through CSS. The conceal function animation is working correctly, but the display function animation does not work correctly. It does not fade in. Instead, it abruptly appears. Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating the bug: https://jsfiddle.net/v6esmqtf/6/.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work correctly"? Please be specific in what you want it to do.

Comment: @discipline updated question

Comment: You didn't set up the display function - jsfiddle.net/ypz7m241/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply didn't have the `display` function set up.

```
Element.prototype.conceal = function(ms) {
  ms = ms || 0;
  var thisStyle = this.style;
  thisStyle.opacity = 0;
  setTimeout(function() {
    thisStyle.display = "none";
  }, ms);
};

Element.prototype.display = function(ms) {
  ms = ms || 0;
  var thisStyle = this.style;
  thisStyle.display = "";
  setTimeout(function() {
    thisStyle.opacity = 1;
  }, ms);
};
```

And then...

```
document.getElementById("conceal").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("get").conceal(800);
};

document.getElementById("display").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("get").display(0);
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's odd that setTimeout() needs to be there, even with no delay. I changed the code to have no parameters in the `display()` function. Instead, I run setTimeout() with zero delay.

Comment: I *think* it's because `opacity` has an inbuilt keyframe times - you could use JQ instead for `$("#get").animate({opacity: '1'}, 5000);` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180504/css-opacity-change-on-div-with-time-delay-not-user-interaction